# Is it appropriate to contact a journal about grammatically erroneous editing?

Tags: journals, editors, journal-workflow, grammar, copy-editing

Recently, I submitted a paper to a maths journal (which is a decent journal with a solid editorial board). It was eventually accepted after making some revisions suggested by the referees, at which point I uploaded my final submission. This final submission was then edited by a copy editor at the journal; as well as the usual cosmetic changes in ensuring that my papered adhered to the cosmetic style of the journal, the copy editor also made several grammatical changes. I then was given an opportunity to read through this edited version and suggest any final corrections before my paper is uploaded to the journal's website.

This, of course, is all fairly standard practice. However, many of the grammatical changes made by the copy editor were incorrect. Of course, I noted this in my comments, so I hope these changes will be reverted before the paper is published.

> It is appropriate for me to take further action in notifying the journal (e.g. a member of the editorial board) that a copy editor is repeatedly introducing errors?

This of course seems a little petty. On the other hand, these same grammatical errors occur repeatedly throughout papers in this journal (at least in recent papers published online), and I'm sure that I'm not the only reader who finds these mistakes irritating.

---

In case anyone is curious about the errors, the most common mistake is that the copy editor repeatedly replaced with a comma my usage of a semicolon before an independent clause, especially such a clause in the imperative mood: an example would be something like "This can be proved via the method of Gauss, see [1]". Other such comma splices were introduced - all by replacing semicolons with commas.

Additional grammatical mistakes were introduced that were clearly incorrect: for example, I perhaps overuse the phrase "Note that", and this was pruned on a couple of occasions by the copy editor, but in more than one case, the rest of the sentence wasn't edited to ensure that it still made sense.

Comment: If this was your paper, and the grammatical change was consistent, what would a neutral third party think? For me personally, I don't understand why punctuation are inside of quotations. "Like this." It makes more sense to me to have it "like this". If I start to program with punctuation (especially commas) inside of quotes, I am gonna have a bad time.

Comment: Just for reference, what is an example of a sentence that becomes incorrect if you remove "note that"?

Comment: I appreciate the irritation, and I used to care more about these things when I was at a similar career stage; but these days I am reminded more and more about the story about Besicovitch's English

Comment: Moreover, if you say that "these same grammatical errors occur repeatedly throughout papers in this journal (at least in recent papers published online)", then this sounds like a matter of house style. You may feel that they are in error, and you may be right, but browsing through both Fowler and various entries on Language Log suggests that more things are merely foklore codifications than one might have first thought. (From a handful of dealings with the copy-editors used by the AMS, they really don't like semicolons.) Therefore ...

Comment: ... while I would not say it is inappropriate for you to notify a member of the editorial board, I would gently suggest it is not the best use of your energies or time - although I believe you are well within your rights to insist on final author approval or corrections to what the sub-editors have done.

Comment: @FedericoPolino: I had written "Note in this case that...", and the copy editor replaced this with "In this case that...", so that the whole sentence became a dependent clause.

Comment: @YemonChoi: While it may be house style, I have not seen these grammatical errors in other journals under the same publishing house. Comma splices are a common grammatical mistake, but it seems extremely strange for me for these to be actively inserted into a manuscript by a copy editor, instead of removed.

Comment: I also ought to mention that many semicolons in my paper were *not* replaced with commas, so this was not a consistent change.

Comment: @Yemon Choi: You mean this? ---- **(from p. 193 of** [**this paper**](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/blms/7.2.191/full)) *Speaking Russian at home, Besicovitch's command of English remained stationary from his early days in Cambridge. For him the definite article was superfluous. A story is told that during one of his lectures an undergraduate tittered at some distortion of English idiom. "Gentlemen", said Besicovitch, "there are fifty million Englishmen speak English you speak; there are five hundred million Russians speak English I speak." There was no further tittering.*

Comment: No.  Pity the poor underpaid copyeditor and just make your corrections.

Comment: Your main goal is to get your paper published correctly, without comma splices and other grammatical errors. Whether complaining to an editor or the publisher will help to prevent introduction of these errors into other papers is not at all clear to me. The use of a comma before "see [1]" is unfortunately so common that I see no hope of globally correcting that error. With other errors, like removing "note" while keeping the associated "that", you might have a better chance. Even so, you surely have better ways to use your time (prove a theorem, play with children, sleep in).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I'm not sure which is more appalling—Besicovitch's mangling of English or of demographics.

Answer (score 3):

I can't give you a yes / no answer, but I can say what's likely to happen if you choose to complain.

If you choose to complain to the **publisher**: chances are they'll ask for some examples of poor copyediting and form their own opinion. If they agree with you, they might change the copyeditor (if it's outsourced) or provide him or her with the negative review and pointers (if it's an in-house employee). If they don't agree with you then probably nothing will happen other than giving you a vague "we are aware of the issue" response.

If you choose to complain to a **member of the editorial board** then:

1. It's possible the editor will say "this is none of my business, approach the publisher", or forward to the publisher "I received this complaint, what do you think" (in which case, see the second paragraph).
2. It's also possible (but in my opinion less likely) that the editor will take things seriously, in which case he or she will contact the publisher. Again, see second paragraph, except this time the publisher is also dealing with an unhappy editorial board member and so would be more inclined to make changes.

Finally if you choose to **just make your corrections** then your corrections get implemented and everyone just moves on to the next paper.

Having said all that, I gotta say, I don't see any difference between "This can be proved via the method of Gauss, see [1]" and "This can be proved via the method of Gauss; see [1]". Both simply say that the reader can find the proof in reference 1. It looks to me like an unnecessary correction, but it isn't *per se* wrong. I checked with another editor and he found both OK too. If you can confidently say that one of them is wrong, you have a level of English mastery that most other native speakers aren't even aware of.

Comment: Copyediting isn't only about meaning; it's about getting the details, like punctuation, right. Copyeditors aren't "most other native speakers." They're supposed to master English mechanics. Entire chapters have been written about commas versus semicolons, and the poster is correct in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Publishers typically have a house "style" to which they adhere. Therefore, minor corrections that otherwise do not change the meaning are likely not an issue.

However, if the edit were to change the *meaning* of a part of your article, or represents an unintended error, then you should *definitely* protest. I have only once had to make a complaint to a publisher, but that was because they introduced significant errors in the *mathematics* in my paper, completely changing the meaning of the paper. In such cases, you should *definitely* notify someone about the problem, because they are significant enough to warrant a corrigendum if they weren't fixed at the proof stage.

Answer (score 0):

"In this case that..." is clearly incorrect. The copyeditor is correct in thinking that "Note that" is usually superfluous. I'm guessing that here the copyeditor was simply sloppy.

Regarding your Gauss example, I think both the comma and semicolon are incorrect. "See [1]" is a parenthetical remark and a citation, so it should be in parentheses, no?

But you're right, the comma before "see" is quite incorrect. As you say, in English a comma can't separate two independent clauses.

At least 90% of copyediting is bound by clear rules. Perhaps 5% of changes are optional, and the remaining 5% are left to the editor's discretion because no style manual covers the question. I've never encountered a house style that broke hard-and-fast rules of the English language, so this doesn't seem like a problem with house style but rather the copyeditor's competence.

I think it would be appropriate to contact the journal about this problem. The copyeditor is paid to do a task competently. If that's not what's happening, the journal should know about it. I wouldn't want my article to be published in worse shape than when I submitted it. That will reflect poorly on you, not the copyeditor.